# Set order of items in the FOREACH

Tags: c#, foreach

My controller passes a list of objects to my view allowing me to:

```
        @foreach (var optiongroup in Model)
        {
```

Within the Model is an `IEnumerable<Option>`. I need to sort this list of options such that when I:

```
@foreach (var option in optiongroup.Options){
```

I end up with a list where items are sorted on the property called `option.SortOrder` instead of the ordinal position of each item.

So how do I get a list sorted prior to the `foreach`? I've tried:

```
@foreach (var option in optiongroup.Options.OrderByDescending(o => optiongroup.SortOrder))
```

and:

```
IEnumerable<Option> allOptions = optiongroup.Options.OrderByDescending(o => optiongroup.SortOrder); 
// then foreaching the allOptions list
```

but have yet to achieve joy.

thx

Comment: You are sorting by optiongroup.SortOrder, which is same for each item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This

```
IEnumerable<Option> allOptions = optiongroup.Options.OrderByDescending(o => optiongroup.SortOrder);
```

should be

```
IEnumerable<Option> allOptions = optiongroup.Options.OrderByDescending(o => o.SortOrder);
```